# Viewflipper not fit my design (fluid layout)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/fondo"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Inicio" >

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/flipper1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rotacion1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_desc"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/rotacion1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rotacion2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_desc"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/rotacion2" />

</ViewFlipper>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="1dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textBienve"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#30c2c2c2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_bienvel"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="menu1"
        android:text="@string/menu1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textMenudia"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#30c2c2c2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_menu"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="menu2"
        android:text="@string/menu2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textEspeciali"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#30c2c2c2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_espec"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="menu3"
        android:text="@string/especialidades"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:paddingTop="1dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCeleb"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#30c2c2c2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_celeb"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="menu4"
        android:text="@string/menu4"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textProvee"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#30c2c2c2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_prove"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="menu5"
        android:text="@string/menu5"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLocalic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#30c2c2c2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_local"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="menu6"
        android:text="@string/menu6"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/fondo"
        android:src="@drawable/iconossocialesf" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#30c2c2c2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="mostrardialog"
        android:text="@string/contacto"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/fondo"
        android:src="@drawable/iconossocialest" />
</LinearLayout>
```

i need that the viewflipper go fluid, but this is not even shown and not adjust to my screen.if I put a size such 200DP all my layouts go down or up according to the screen size, i only want to adjust all the layouts to max screen size.
what I do wrong?